# using jQuery get the selected list value from dynamically created item

Tags: php, jquery

im trying to get the value of selected item, my items are dynamically generated

```
foreach ($result as $value){

?>

  <a href="#" class="badge badge-info filteredcat" value="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>">
    <?php echo $value['categorie'] ?>
  </a>  

<?php    
}
?>
```

so after it loads the html looks like this

```
<a href="#" class="badge badge-info filteredcat" value="5">
    Semnalizare rutieră  </a>  


  <a href="#" class="badge badge-info filteredcat" value="4">
    Probleme de mediu  </a>  


  <a href="#" class="badge badge-info filteredcat" value="6">
    Spații verzi  </a>  


  <a href="#" class="badge badge-info filteredcat" value="7">
    Câini comunitari  </a>
```

using jquery i want to get the value of selected item

```
 $('.filteredcat').click(function(){
        let categorie = $(this).val();
        //$.fn.startLoader();


        console.log(categorie);



    });
```

but i cant get the value ... if i use $(this).text() its working ... but not the value

Comment: You should be able to grab it with `let categorieVal = $(this).attr("value");` since it is one of the elements' attributes. See [.attr() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: yes, thank you, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to grab it with `let categorieVal = $(this).attr("value");` since it is one of the elements' attributes. See [.attr() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)